# Creating boxplot based on three variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

How is it possible to create a box plot like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OilRS.png)

```
data.frame(category = c(2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3), educational_years = c(6, 15, 16, 6, 6, 6, 12, 12, 12, 4, 12, 15, 6, 4), gender = c("M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F"))
```

from a data frame like this and x axis have the category y axis age and factor gender

Comment: How is this different from your question from a half hour ago? If you have additional information to add, you should edit the previous one. Just like in that question, this should include a clear example of what you're asking for and what you've tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough data to create a boxplot like the one shown. For example, you only have a single data point for category 1, so you will only get a single horizontal line here. You only have "M" values for category 2, so you will only get a single box here. You have only a single value for "M" in category three, so you will get a horizontal line instead of a box.

Assuming this is only a sample of your data, rather than the full data set, the code would look like this:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(factor(category), educational_years, fill = gender)) + 
  geom_boxplot()
```

At the moment, the result obtained looks like this:

[image]